# PUT Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to doing Ajax request and have put together the following [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3394114). Line 107 is my $.PUT and is throwing an error in firebug that $.PUT does not a function. As for the ajax request I know this is wrong however I am quite lost as to what I need to do inside the success function addCell. Am I going the right way about this?

Edited

```
function _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, method) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: "slot_days/show",
        data: data,
        success: function(data)
        {
callback($.put('/slot_days/show', { '/slot_days/': 'slot_times' }, function(result) 

            {

            });
          )
        }
    });
}

jQuery.extend({
    put: function(url, data, callback, type) {
        return _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, 'PUT');
}});
```

Comment: What u required is PUT or POST ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have an error here (the `success` function must be anonymous):

```
return 
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'slot_days/show',
        data: data,
        success: function addCell() {

        }
    });
```

Should be:

```
function _ajax_request(url, data, callback, method) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

and to extend jQuery:

```
jQuery.extend({
    put: function(url, data, callback) {
        return _ajax_request(url, data, callback, 'PUT');
}});
```

and a sample usage example:

```
$.put('/url', { 'foo': 'bar' }, function(result) {
    // do something with the results of the AJAX call
});
```

Comment: @Djj, no, I meant that you have invalid javascript out there. The problem is not that it is empty. We will see this later. The problem is that in your code you wrote: `success: function addCell() { }` which is invalid. It must be `success: function () { }`. And if you wanted to invoke some function that was passed as parameter for example you could: `success: callback`.

Comment: @Djj, of course that you can. Simply pass it as 3rd argument of the `$.put` method: `$.put("/" + getDiaryId() + "/slot_days/" + getSlotId + "/slot_times/" + 0, slot_time, addCell);`

Comment: Like this: `success: addCell($.put("/" + getDiaryId() + "/slot_days/" + getSlotId + "/slot_times/" + 0, slot_time, addCell))
`

Comment: No, that's invalid javascript.

Comment: Right, so that would be "/slot_days"? This is essentially this is the problem I am receiving http://i.imgur.com/PpPnB.png every time I press the 'plus' button.

Comment: @Djj, no you should pass a function to the success callback. Like `success: addCell` or `success: function() { whatever(); }`.

Comment: @Djj, no, that's not what I mean at all. Read my answer once again. I mean: `success: function(result) { callback(); }`.

Comment: Darin, maybe you should add a usage example to your answer. Actually, things should be clear by now, but still ...

Comment: @SebastianWramba, sure, I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Darin in the example you provided `$.put('/url', { 'foo': 'bar' }, function(result) {
    // do something with the results of the AJAX call
});` are you expecting me to put that within the success function. Because previous to that you said that it was suppose to be `success: function(result) { callback(); }`

Comment: @Djj, you can use the $.put whenever you want to send a PUT AJAX request.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is what I have okay?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov If you see my post I added the code of what I have. I added the 8 minutes ago before you replied

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Or did you mean that if I wanted to use the $.put this `$.put('/url', { 'foo': 'bar' }, function(result) {` is how I'd use it in my show.html.erb?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I sorted half of the issue I was having. It was because I didn't include my ajax_request_PUT in the head properly. I did <%= javascript_include_tag "ajax_request_PUT

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not including the `_ajax_request_PUT.js` in your main file. This is why the function `$.put` cannot be found. Include it first, then your error will disappear.

Comment: Right okay, this may sound daft but how would I do this?

Comment: Just like you include jquery. `<script src="path/to/_ajax_request_PUT.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"`

Comment: I included the file into my main file still receiving the same error. It is most probably something to do with my success function and the callback

Comment: Yes probably, see Darin Dimitrovs answer for that problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response though

Answer (score 0):

See the simple and clean answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/916632
Just change the type value to "PUT".

Also handles the 415 response that might be causing problems for others (it blocked me). Also the 400 response in terms of the data object sent.