# POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc

Tags: ajax, json, spring, post, http-status-code-415

I am trying to send a POST request to a servlet. Request is sent via jQuery in this way:

```
var productCategory = new Object();
productCategory.idProductCategory = 1;
productCategory.description = "Descrizione2";
newCategory(productCategory);
```

where newCategory is

```
function newCategory(productCategory)
{
  $.postJSON("ajax/newproductcategory", productCategory, function(
      idProductCategory)
  {
    console.debug("Inserted: " + idProductCategory);
  });
}
```

and postJSON is

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': callback
    });
};
```

With firebug I see that JSON is sent correctly:

```
{"idProductCategory":1,"description":"Descrizione2"}
```

But I get 415 Unsupported media type. Spring mvc controller has signature

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/newproductcategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Integer newProductCategory(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestBody ProductCategory productCategory)
```

Some days ago it worked, now it is not. I'll show more code if needed.

Comment: What have you changed since some days ago? Also, wouldn't `var productCategory = { idProductCategory: 1, description: "Descrizione2" };` be more concise and easier to read? Do you need to tell Spring to accept `application/json` specifically? In other words, is it expecting the data to come in a form?

Comment: A lot of things since I was working on other part of this project, and today I found this regression. In this part I did not change anything.
Yes, I have to use this way because I am getting input from a form.

Comment: No you're not, you're getting it from a JSON Ajax post, which is not the same as form encoded data.

Comment: Sorry I misread. I am getting input from a form but without submit. In Spring I use Jackson to deserialize data to an object.

Comment: Are you sure Jackson is still available on your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Yes. However, maybe I found a solution: I use custom serializers and deserializers; question: Jackson annotation JSONDeserialize() and definition of a custom object mapper where to register deserializer, are in mutual exclusion? Because registering a deserializer in custom object mapper and commenting JSONDeserialize() annotation on target class (ProductCategory) did the trick..

Comment: I got the same issue, but my problem was cross-domain

Comment: if u send text/json instead of application/json u get the same error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed out how to make it works. Tell me in case I am wrong.
I used only one way to serialize/deserialize: I removed all annotations regarding this (`@JSONSerialize` and `@JSONDeserialize`) and registered Serializers and Deserializers in `CustomObjectMapper` class.
I didn't find an article explaining this behaviour but I resolved in this way. Hope it's useful.

Comment: Happens the same to me! Any explanation why it happens?

Comment: Can you please explain your method in detail??

Answer (score 281):

I've had this happen before with Spring @ResponseBody and it was because there was no accept header sent with the request. Accept header can be a pain to set with jQuery, but this worked for me [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6692376/936869)

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': callback
    });
};
```

The Content-Type header is used by @RequestBody to determine what format the data being sent from the client in the request is. The accept header is used by @ResponseBody to determine what format to sent the data back to the client in the response. That's why you need both headers.

Comment: the headers: {...} and the JSON.stringify(...) always trip me up.

Comment: No idea why this isn't more documented. This problem made me waste so much time. Thank you very much!

Comment: I expected Spring does support form data by default, but it doesn't. So, thanks for the (now rather old) solution.

Comment: I was using a postman to make a put request, just added content-type: ''application/json". thank you

Comment: i had  contentType  = "applicaton/json"   spelling counts!

Answer (score 34):

adding content type into the request as `application/json` resolved the issue

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem but found the issue was that I had neglected to provide a default constructor for the DTO that was annotated with @RequestBody.

Comment: same thing happened to me. I had 2 methods with the same name and was getting 415. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I faced a similar issue and this is how I fixed it,

The problem is due to the conversion process from JSON to Java, one need to have the right run time jackson libraries for the conversion to happen correctly.

Add the following jars (through dependency or by downloading and adding to the classpath.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This should fix the problem.

Complete Code:

```
function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveUserDetails.do",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      name: "Gerry",
      ity: "Sydney"
    }),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.status == 'OK')
        alert('Person has been added');
      else
        alert('Failed adding person: ' + data.status + ', ' + data.errorMessage);
}
```

and the controller signature looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUserDetails.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Person addPerson( @RequestBody final  Person person) {
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Only `jackson-databind` is required.

Answer (score 12):

I believe I ran exactly into the same issue. After countless hours of fighting with the JSON, the JavaScript and the Server, I found the culprit: In my case I had a Date object in the DTO, this Date object was converted to a String so we could show it in the view with the format: HH:mm.

When JSON information was being sent back, this Date String object had to be converted back into a full Date Object, therefore we also need a method to set it in the DTO. The big BUT is you cannot have 2 methods with the same name (Overload) in the DTO even if they have different type of parameter (String vs Date) because this will give you also the 415 Unsupported Media type error.

This was my controller method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/alarmdownload/update", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody
  StatusResponse update(@RequestBody AlarmDownloadDTO[] rowList) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    return new StatusResponse();
  }
```

This was my DTO example (id get/set and preAlarm get Methods are not included for code shortness):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AlarmDownloadDTO implements Serializable {

  private static final SimpleDateFormat formatHHmm = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

  private String id;
  private Date preAlarm;

  public void setPreAlarm(Date date) { 
    this.preAlarm == date;
  }
  public void setPreAlarm(String date) {    
    try {
      this.preAlarm = formatHHmm.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      this.preAlarm = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
      this.preAlarm = null;
    }
  }
}
```

To make everything work you need to remove the method with Date type parameter. This error is very frustrating. Hope this can save someone hours of debugging.

Comment: Thanks - or you can just rename one of the setters. I had both `public void setParameters(List<Parameter> parameters)` & `public void setParameters(Parameter... parameters)` methods in a bean, changing the latter to `addParameters` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the body is this.preAlarm == date rather than this.preAlarm = date ?

Answer (score 8):

I faced this issue when I integrated spring boot with spring mvc. I solved it by just adding these dependencies.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

A small side note - stumbled upon this same error while developing a web application. The mistake we found, by toying with the service with Firefox Poster, was that both fields and values in the Json should be surrounded by double quotes. For instance..

```
[ {"idProductCategory" : "1" , "description":"Descrizione1"}, 
  {"idProductCategory" : "2" , "description":"Descrizione2"} ]
```

In our case we filled the json via javascript, which can be a little confusing when it comes with dealing with single/double quotes, from what I've heard.

What's been said before in this and other posts, like including the 'Accept' and 'Content-Type' headers, applies too.

Hope t'helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to follow these steps to resolve the issue:

**1. Make sure you have the following dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
    </dependency>
```

**2. Create the following filter:**

```
    public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String origin = request.getHeader("origin");
            origin = (origin == null || origin.equals("")) ? "null" : origin;
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Authorization, origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with");

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**3. Apply the above filter for the requests in web.xml**

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.your.package.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I hope this is useful to somebody.

Comment: `jackson-core` is a [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.8.1) of `jackson-databind`, so no need to add it directly.

Comment: Why it is necessary to add the CORS filter?

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot + spring mvn

with issue

```
@PostMapping("/addDonation")
public String addDonation(@RequestBody DonatorDTO donatorDTO) {
```

with solution

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addDonation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public GenericResponse addDonation(final DonatorDTO donatorDTO, final HttpServletRequest request){
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding jackson-json data binding to my pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model Class add a json property annotation, also have a default constructor

```
@JsonProperty("user_name")
private String userName;

@JsonProperty("first_name")
private String firstName;

@JsonProperty("last_name")
private String lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. adding

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

to the spring-xml solved it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the Accept and Content-Type headers, and making sure they match the consumes/produces settings for your controller method, you may also want to look at the JSON structure and making sure there are no issues with marshalling and unmarshalling. In my case the content type was OK, but there were issues with mapping JSON requests to my request/response model. Normally the controller should return a 400 error rather than a 415 error, but in my case the error code was 415. I debugged the issue by adding a test class where I used an ObjectMapper to read my JSON into the request model object. The ObjectMapper choked on the request, and gave me helpful errors that helped me fix my model class definition.

Answer (score -1):

1.a. Add following in  applicationContext-mvc.xml

xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc

2. add jackson library