# Why json data of ajax call ended up as querystring parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call. I want to send out the data in jason format. However I noticed in Fiddler that the data is converted to query string parameters. What I am doing wrong?

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "StatusService.svc/CheckStatus",
        data: JSON.stringify({"companyName":"paymins"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok!');
            alter(data.toString());
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Because you're doing a `get` request.

Comment: Note that `dataType: "json"` tells jQuery the expected format of the _response,_ not the format of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of your request to a post.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "StatusService.svc/CheckStatus",
        data: JSON.stringify({"companyName":"paymins"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok!');
            alter(data.toString());
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try specifying your headers as updated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc

Comment: It's mine own WCF service configuration problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Get cannot contain a body. Use post for that.