# sending a post request to Rest Client in firefox

Tags: http, post, rest-client

i am using **Rest Client** add on in **firefox** web browser.I want to test a web service that processes a **HTTP POST** request and consumes json.How do i test it using Rest Client?

If i put a json in the **request body** i get a ****HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type error****.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I used to face this issue if the header 'Content-Type': 'application/json' is not added. 
Also refer [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc), around the same lines.

Comment: Did the trick - thanks!  It also helped me to be looking at Response Body (Raw) tab instead of Response Headers