# Getting Network Error 415 - Unsupported Media Type

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, soap

In my HTML5 app I am getting an "Unsupported Media Type" error, when I try to call SOAP web services.

Here is the code of my javascript function.

```
function login()
{
    var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blu="http://www.bluedoortech.com/">'+
    '<soapenv:Header/>'+
    '<soapenv:Body>'+
        '<blu:Connect>'+
            '<blu:userID>' +  $("#txtUserName").val() + '</blu:userID>'+
            '<blu:pwd>' + $("#txtPassword").val() + '</blu:pwd>'+
        '</blu:Connect>'+
    '</soapenv:Body>'+
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';


    $.ajax({
        url : 'Wealth.asmx' ,
        data: soapMessage,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        cache : false,
        processData: false
    }).success(function(xmlDoc,textStatus) {
        alert($(xmlDoc).text());
    });
}[1]
```

Here I attached a screen of the error as well.

For testing purposes I made a php file and I used that php file to call this SOAP web service. It works very well when I connect to the web service. Here is the PHP code.

```
        header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
        $soap_request = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($soap_request);

        $userIDTag = $xml->xpath('//blu:userID');
        $userID = $userIDTag[0][0];

        $passwordIDTag = $xml->xpath('//blu:pwd');
        $password = $passwordIDTag[0][0];

        $client = new SoapClient("Wealth.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => true));
        $objLogin =  $client->Connect(array('userID'=>$userID,'pwd'=>$password));

        echo $client->__getLastResponse();
```

Kindly help me with identifying the issue.

Comment: How about adding `contentType: "text/xml"` to the ajax call?

Comment: Joachim Isaksson is right : you send "xml" data without declaring it as such. Google for "unsupported media type" : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325 ...

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will check using those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joachim Isaksson suggested, I have added the content type header and it's work well now. I am posting it here too.

```
function login()
{
    var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blu="http://www.bluedoortech.com/">'+
    '<soapenv:Header/>'+
    '<soapenv:Body>'+
        '<blu:Connect>'+
            '<blu:userID>' +  $("#txtUserName").val() + '</blu:userID>'+
            '<blu:pwd>' + $("#txtPassword").val() + '</blu:pwd>'+
        '</blu:Connect>'+
    '</soapenv:Body>'+
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';


    $.ajax({
        url : 'Wealth.asmx' ,
        data: soapMessage,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"text/xml"
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        cache : false,
        processData: false
    }).success(function(xmlDoc,textStatus) {
        alert($(xmlDoc).text());
    });
}
```