# Converting JSON array into java List<String> with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I have a list of string in my javascript code which I send via JQuery to a REST based service as follows:

```
var ids = []; 
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    ids.push(this.id);
});
var selectedIds = JSON.stringify(ids);
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", selectedIds,function(e) {
}, "json");
```

As you can see, I convert a javascript array into a JSON array.

Now, in the server side, I use Spring MVC and Jackson to receive and parse the input JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tasks/removeTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String removeTask(@RequestBody List<String> selectedIds) {
    ...
}
```

But I always get:

```
HTTP Status 415 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report message 

description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format     not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

I tried to remove the quotes from the JSON object, and also tried using `@RequestParam` without success.

Update as per OQJF suggestion:

I modified my post request as follows:

```
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", {selectedIds: selectedIds},function(e) {  
}, "json");
```

Now my controller method gets called, but each `List` element is populated with the double quotes and brackets. This the List argument:

```
[["15", "21"]]
```

So e.g. the first element looks like:

```
["15"
```

I would prefer not to parse each `String` element of the `List`.

I also tried removing the `JSON.stringify` conversion but my controller didn't even get called. With this I got:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 'selectedIds' is not present

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Required List parameter 'selectedIds' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

**Update**

I tried to create an object to hold my ids, as follows:

```
public class TaskIdHolder {

    private String[] selectedIds;

    public String[] getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedIds;
    }

    public void setSelectedIds(String[] selectedIds) {
        this.selectedIds = selectedIds;
    }
}
```

Then I modified my controller method signature:

```
public @ResponseBody String removeTask(@RequestBody TaskIdHolder selectedIds) {
```

And my JSON request looks like this:

```
{"selectedIds":["15"]}
```

I also modified my Jquery code as per Andrei's suggestion:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({selectedIds:selectedIds});
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", data, function(e) {
```

Where selectedIds is a JavaScript array.

But now I get:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/todonotes/tasks/removeTask 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc can help you with updated question.

Comment: One of the solutions in this post has worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the the request parameter an explicit name:

```
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", {selectedIds: selectedIds},...
```

**Update**. You can also try to stringify the whole request data object to JSON:

```
var data = {selectedIds: selectedIds};
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", JSON.stringify(data),...
```

Comment: Thanks. Got some progress. I still have some issues with the List argument. Please see my question updated.

Comment: @GonzaloGarciaLasurtegui, please have a look at the updated answer - this should help.

Comment: I tried this with @RequestBody annotation. Please see a new update in my question.

Answer (score 4):

As I know that you don't need to use `JSON.stringify(),` your code can be like this:

```
var ids = []; 
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    ids.push(this.id);
});

$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", $.param({'id': ids}, true),function(e) {
}, "json");
```

And on the server side, you should specify the value of:

```
public methodName(@RequestParam("id") List<String> selectedIds)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, no need to change your controller's method signature or create an object to hold your ids.

```
$.post("/todonotes/tasks/removeTask", {selectedIds: selectedIds.join(',')},function(e) {  
}, "json");
```

That way you'll be sending your ids like `selectedIds: id1,id2,id3` which is how the Controller is expecting them to be if you declare your request param to be `String[]` or `List<String>` (works for both scenarios).