# Mapping JSON to Hibernate models in Spring REST Controllers

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

Let's say that I have a Spring 4 web application with a Hibernate-based persistence layer.  I'd like to create a `RestController` that supports basic CRUD operations for my models.  Creating a method for fetching records works without a hitch:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Stuff> getStuff(){
    return stuffService.findAll();
}
```

Jackson handles the object serialization, no problem.  But what if I want to add a method for creating new records via a POST request?  Is there any easy way to support a simple method like this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer getStuff(@RequestParam("stuff") Stuff stuff){
    return stuffService.save(stuff);
}
```

Is something like this possible?  Or do I need to manually map posted form data to a new object?

**SOLUTION**

Here is how I solved my problem, there were a couple steps.  First, my final controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer getStuff(@RequestBody Stuff stuff){
    return stuffService.save(stuff);
}
```

I already had a filter applied to all requests to the application API, to allow cross origin resource sharing, but modifications to this were needed to allow requests to specify content type:

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter{

    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

    }

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override public void destroy() { }
}
```

Which is registered in my `web.xml` file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.app.util.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now when I make a request, such as the one below, it will correctly map my submitted JSON to my model and persist a new instance:

```
var stuff = {
    name: "Some stuff",
    description: "This is some stuff."
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(stuff),
    contentType: "application/json"
  }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(x, status, e){
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Is the content an html form POST or JSON?

Comment: @Affe: JSON, sent either by a browser AJAX request or via a Spring `RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell Spring that you want it to apply a deserializer to the content instead of attempt standard HTML form binding you use `@RequestBody`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Integer getStuff(@RequestBody Stuff stuff){
    return stuffService.save(stuff);
}
```

`@RequestParam` is telling it to look for an individual parameter with that name and apply standard databinding, not to deserialize the entire content of the POST into an object.

Comment: Do I need to explicitly set `consumes = "application/something"`?  Or will it expect the proper JSON format?  Are any additional request headers needed?

Comment: Only if you want to route requests with different headers to different places or lock it down.  For simple things the out-of-the-box `<mvc:annotation-driven />` will "get it right."  (note if you specify consumes, requests with valid content but missing the header will be turned away, you may or may not want that.)

Comment: Writing my controller method like you have it results in `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` errors.  Another SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) suggests altering the request headers, but this did not help either.

Comment: Did you configure your dispatcher with mvc:annotation-driven or set it up manually?  Is Jackson on the classpath?

Comment: I used `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, but with a modification (see above).  Jackson is on the classpath and working fine for object serialization.

Comment: Try adding `<property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />` to the message converter bean?

Comment: Well, I don't actually know anything about the project "com.fasterxml" but might wildly speculate that implementation of ObjectMapper might only support.... xml?  Maybe register a separate converter for json?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This answer is technically correct, though there was some additional configuration I needed to do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. Jackson will automatically do a two-way mapping of entities, so if you want to `POST` something to the server just use the same JSON format that you see when you do `GET`.