# Spring 4 Error 415 Unsupported Media Type Error

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, model-view-controller

Running my Java code is always returning a 415 error. I'm using Spring 4.1.5 and fasterxml Jackson (core and databind) 2.5.2

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mainvm")
public class MainVMController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/init",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Object> init() {...}
}
```

The JavaScript is a simple HTTP GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "mainvm/init",
    dataType : 'json',
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    }
}).done(function() {}
```

The Spring context :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="it.staer" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate/Jdbc Configuration -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
</bean>

<!-- Resolver/mapping configuration -->

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/ui/**" location="/ui/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>  
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Can someone point out the problem?

Comment: Is the controller correctly registered? And have you had a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You wish that Spring automagically converts incoming JSON into objects and outgoing objects into JSON, don't you?

If so, then you should configure a [MessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-message-conversion)!

You can define the converter inside the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` declaration. Example:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" 
              class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"  />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Optional, and only if you want Spring to convert the request body contents (e.g. some JSON) into a domain object (or a `Map<String, String>`) for you, you should use the [@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestbody) annotation.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Spring needs to be version 4.0.x.