# Unsupported media type 415 in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to post the data, when I click on save I am getting 415 unsupported media type in the browser. One more observation I would like to add is, when I am sending data using POSTMAN  to the application in JSON format then, the data is getting persisted in the database and is coming fine in the view. If using above angular code the issue still persists.

js code -

```
$scope.addUser = function addUser() {
var user={};
console.log("["+$scope.user.firstName+"]");
         $http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert/',$scope.user)
            .success(function(data) {
             $scope.users = data;   
             $scope.user="";
             $scope.toggle='!toggle';            
            });
        };
```

Controller code -

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/users/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
     public @ResponseBody List<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws ParseException {    
        //get the values from user object and send it to impl class
  }
```

Comment: You are posting an object as part of the uri. You most likely want to have it as part of the body.

Answer (score 1):

Path variable can take only string values. you are passing "user" in path and in Controller method, addUser(), you are expecting of the type User class. As this is not a standard type like Integer or Float for which String to Integer converters are already available by default in Spring, you are expected to provide a converter from String to User.

You can refer this [link](https://machiel.me/post/java-enums-as-request-parameters-in-spring-4/) for creating and registering converters.

As suggested by @Shawn, as you are posting an serialized object in request path, it is cleaner and better practice to pass it as request body. You can do something like the following.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws ParseException { 
    //get the values from user object and send it to impl class
}
```

And pass user as request body in your ajax call. change js code to

```
//you need to add request headers
$http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert',JSON.stringify($scope.user)).success...
```

or

```
//with request headers
$http({
    url: urlBase + 'users/insert',
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.user),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept' : 'application/json'}
  }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.users = data;   
         $scope.user="";
         $scope.toggle='!toggle';            
        });
};
```

Add these request headers Content-Type: application/json and Accept: application/json .
Similar issue posted on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/5039001

Comment: ok, So, I have corrected the same as mentioned above, but now getting `/users/insert/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)` in the browser. controller is same as mentioned and js is as `$http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert',$scope.user)` .How to deal with this ?

Comment: Add these request headers Content-Type: application/json and Accept: application/json . change js code to $http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert',JSON.stringify($scope.user)). Similar issue posted on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/5039001

Comment: You don't need any of those headers, nor JSON.stringify(). angular does that for you. Just pass the object, and $http will transform it to JSON.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I ahve passed the object only. Please check my previous comments.

Comment: @prem kumar, i checked with the changes you told. but still issue persists.