# Error: Unsupported Media Type (Codename One)

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-8

I'm trying to send a POST request from my CN1 app on NetBeans IDE but im getting this error each time i run the app "Error 415: Unsupported Media Type". here are my codes:

Request Code:

```
@Override
    protected void onMain_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    String name=findTextField(c).getText();
    String qty=findTextField1(c).getText();

    ConnectionRequest r= new ConnectionRequest(){                       
           @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {                              
                 }                  
           };    
       r.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/webservicess/webresources/getreq/post");
       r.setPost(true);
       r.setHttpMethod("POST");       
       r.addArgument("name", name);
       r.addArgument("quantity", qty);
       NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);          
    }
```

}

REST Service

```
@POST
    @Path("post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(Product product) {

        String result = "Product recieved : " + product;
        System.out.println(""+result);
    }
}
```

Product.java class

```
class Product {
    public String name;
    public int quantity;

    Product(){

    }
```

}

Please check the attached picture for the screenshot of the error message. 
I want a situation whereby when i click on the Submit button the value entered for product name and quantity should be displayed on the REST console. Please come to my rescue on this.

[image: simulator screenshot]

Best Regards,

Yahya-Imam Munir Kolapo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)

You need to set the accept request header which you can do in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) thru [addRequestHeader](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#addRequestHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
r.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
```

The other problem you are having is a bit misleading but I'm guessing the webservice accepts JSON in the body and not standard post arguments so this should probably work:

```
final String name = findTextField(c).getText();
final String qty = findTextField1(c).getText();

ConnectionRequest r= new ConnectionRequest(){    
        @Override
        protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder("{\"name\":\"");
            val.append(name);
            val.append("\",\"quantity\":");
            val.append(qty);
            val.append("}");
            if(shouldWriteUTFAsGetBytes()) {
                os.write(val.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            } else {
                OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                w.write(val.toString());
            }                                  
        }
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {                              
        }                  
       };    
   r.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/webservicess/webresources/getreq/post");
   r.setPost(true);
   NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you for your response. I added the line as you have suggested but i got another error message "Error 400: Bad Request" . I tried to fix the error by using the approach i got from this site http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/404error.htm but no luck. Please kindly look into this for me.

Comment: Hi Shai, i'm very grateful for your prompt response. Yes i added what you suggested and also went through the link but NO luck yet. I think the problem is with my REST because when i tried to post some values through Chrome Poster I got the same error message "Error 415: Unsupported Media Type".  I have added a screenshot of the Chrome Poster in Codename One discussion forum. I will continue trying. Thank you once again im very grateful.

Comment: If get works and post fails then why did you use setPost(true) instead of false?

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for your prompt response. When I use r.setPost(false); I still get the same error message: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Did you remove the `r.setHttpMethod("POST");` line too (FYI its redundant for post and for get calls).

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you for your prompt technical support. I remove r.setHttpMethod("POST"); as suggested but another error message came up saying: Error 405: Method Not Allowed. I will attach the screenshot and the code at codename one forum. Please kindly check it for me. Thank you

Comment: I think I see the problem, I was mislead when you mentioned get working. The issue is that your original implementation just added standard post arguments but JSON should be sent in the body for the request. I did a relatively simple example of how I think it should look but you need to check it as I did not run it.

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you so much for all the assistance and supports. Im sorry for the misleading comment. I tried the above code but no luck yet. It shows: "Error 415: Unsupported Media Type". I added r.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json"); but still no luck. I also tried to pass "val" as an argument r.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/webservicess/webresources/getreq/post/"+val); but I got another error message: Error 404: Not Found. I will keep on trying. Thank you once again and have a pleasant day.

Comment: That won't work. You need to use either get or post. Try to get this to work with a JSON testing tool like https://www.soapui.org/ assuming it works with a configuration from there you can figure out where the code differs in what it is trying to do.

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you very much for your kindness. Finally the code works. I just added this line: r.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); I have pasted the complete code on CN1 forum. Please kindly help me to check if am actually doing the right thing. Thank you once again i'm very grateful.