# Sending List of objects from javascript to Spring web service results in empty object

Tags: javascript, java, spring, api, model-view-controller

I have a few classes in my web service, one with an BookingTable object and the other, a wrapper containing a list of BookingTable objects and a bookingController class to handle the requests.

BookingTable.java

```
package com.webservice;

import java.util.List;

public class BookingTable {
    private String deskID;
    private List<String> dates;

    public BookingTable(){}

    public void setDeskID(String id){
        this.deskID=id;
    }
    public String getDeskID(){
        return deskID;
    }
    public void setDates(List<String> dates){
        this.dates=dates;
    }
    public List<String> getDates(){
        return dates;
    }
}
```

BookingTableWrapper.java

```
package com.webservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookingTableWrapper {

    private List<BookingTable> bookingTables = new ArrayList<>();

    public BookingTableWrapper() {}

    public List<BookingTable> getBookingTables() {
        return bookingTables;
    }

    public void setBookingTables(List<BookingTable> bookingTables) {
        this.bookingTables = bookingTables;
    }
}
```

(part of) BookingController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> test(@ModelAttribute BookingTableWrapper bookingTableWrapper) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hi");
}
```

I am sending am AJAX request in JavaScript like this:

```
    var bookingTableWrapper = 
            {
                "bookingTables": [{
                    "deskID": "1",
                    "dates": ["1", "2", "3"]
                }, {
                    "deskID": "2",
                    "dates": ["4","5","6"]
                }]
            }




    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/test", 
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(bookingTableWrapper)
    })
```

This request come into the backend but is not creating the object. All I see it a null object. I tried with just the BookingTable object and it works fine, but when I try the BookingTableWrapper, I get nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Response containing empty object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQLaP.png)

[Response/Request Headers and what's being posted in Firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwxBE.png)

Comment: How does the http request and headers look like in firebug or chrome network tag or similar?

Comment: send your json request from rest client and check you are getting null object or not.

Comment: I have attached a picture above for the response/request headers

Comment: @Vaibs, sorry what do you mean exactly? I am sending this and it results in an empty object, I have tried sending through Postman and I get the same.

Comment: by using rest client you can send the data to controller.You can use advance rest client or postman or insomnia.Also you can post thru curl command.For rest client just go to google chrome->open new tab->clickon App(Present Left side) and search for rest client which i mentioned.By using that you will know where it is the exact issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tried it with postman before, but there is no error, the response it fine. But the problem is the object in the rest side is showing as empty.

Comment: I tried your code on local envi.Its working fine .Just use below code and try once . @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody BookingTableWrapper bookingTableWrapper) {
       System.out.println("Element " +bookingTableWrapper.getBookingTables().get(0).getDeskID());
     return ResponseEntity.ok("Hi");
 }

Comment: @Vaibs I have tried this and it is now giving me this error: "NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - http://localhost:8080/test"

Comment: Add dependacy    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I think I have found something, I added a headers tag to my js request, found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc), I combined this with your advice and there seems to be something,. I will test further and update

Comment: Yes, That is now working! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the controller to this as suggested by @Vaibs:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody BookingTableWrapper bookingTableWrapper) {
    System.out.println("Element " +bookingTableWrapper.getBookingTables().get(0).getDeskID());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hi"); 
    }
```

This gave an error:

> NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - localhost:8080/test";

So I added some header tags to my AJAX request, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) post.

```
$.ajax({
         headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/test", 
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(bookingTableWrapper)
    })
```

This now works.
Thank you @Vaibs!