# Unsupported Media Type when Posting JSON data to API using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-3

I am posting data to an API using JQuery 3 as follows:

```
$.post({ url: "api/questions", data: { content: "Content" }, dataType: "json" })
  .done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(message);
  })
  .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Unsupported Media Type
```

I am not sure why this happens. I tested my API using PostMan to send a Post request with the following Body:

```
{
  content: "Content"
}
```

And it worked fine ... What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': callback
    });
};
```

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) answer)