# Sending JSON object to Spring POST controller

Tags: json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a **JSON** object by **AJAX** to a Spring controller but receive an error 415:

`"The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."`

My Spring controller looks like this and is running on Tomcat 7 -

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/ab/greeting", 
    method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*",
    produces = "application/json")
public String greetingSubmit(@RequestBody Person p1) {
    return "result";
}
```

The Person class is defined like this -

```
package ab;

public class Person {

    String fname;
    String lname;
}
```

Here is my javascript making the call -

```
function getGreeting() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/ab/greeting",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ fname: "John", lname: "Doe" }),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Here are my dependencies Jackson related dependencies in my POM -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Ironically, it works when I try it on Spring Boot.

On Tomcat, I have also tried using `@ModelAttribute` in place of `@RequestBody` - in which case, the request returns with a `error code 200` but the p1 object comes out null in the controller.

Is this related to the difference between Spring and Spring MVC? - apologies for the noob question. My controller class is annotated only with `@Controller`.

How do I modify this to be able to send a JSON object from AJAX to Spring POST controller? Eventually, I would like to send an array of 5 objects.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: can you try replacing you jquery ajax post code to   contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "fname": "John", "lname": "Doe" }),
        cache: false, 
        processData: false also try replacing this in spring controller  @RequestMapping(value = "/ab/greeting", 
method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: maybe a duplicate of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc

Comment: Thanks for the replies...I tried both but get the same result as before

Answer (score 2):

Add the *consumes* attribute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ab/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
public String greetingSubmit(@RequestBody Person p1) {
    return "result";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried this but get the same result as before

Comment: @lenniekid did you check that the parameters are correctly sent in the post request? maybe you could try to change the data to this: data: { fname: "John", lname: "Doe" }

Comment: @lenniekid if you don't get enough info with the previous comment, add the next parameter to your method "BindingResult result" then you will be able to extract more info about the problem

Comment: It works when I use @RequestBody String p1 instead of RequestBody Person p1 - any idea why? Thanks a lot - appreciate all the help.

Comment: Does it mean there is some issue with conversion by Jackson?

Comment: I would say your message sent to the request is not in a right JSON format, I would try to simplify your request and check the message. Check you have all getters/setters and the class implements serializable, (Person) remove "headers" attribute, and lets debug whats the problem, you are pretty close!

Comment: @lenniekid in your ajax POST call add this dataType: "json" and remove contentType

Comment: For now, I have fixed the problem by converting the String to object using Gson library. As you pointed out, the problem likely is the absence of setters and getters and serializable interface. Will try that later and keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Tried adding setters and getters and implement the serializable interface now but no effect

Comment: some error or more detailed message when you added the BindingResult to the method? add a breakpoint and inspect that object to check the exception

Comment: some new info??

Answer (score 0):

write data to js console which comes from your view and check your data that it is null or not

Comment: This sounds like a comment, not an answer.