# POST http://localhost:9000/saveuserpermissions 415 (Unsupported Media Type)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, playframework

Here is my Json response having action class in controller,and model class also representing the Json Format,having field to hold the Json Array.**Im getting unsupported media,**
Where do I went wrong.Needed help.

```
  //rest API
       var permissions = {
                        "admin":$scope.adminItems }

     $scope.submit = function(permissions) 
                    {
                    var URL = "/saveuserpermissions";
                    var req = {
                        method : "POST",
                        url : URL,
                        data : JSON.stringify(permissions,{}),
                        headers :{
                            'Content-Type':'application/json'   
                        }
                    };
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
                    return $http(req); 

                };

//controller Action

    def saveUserPermissions = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
        request.body.validate[RolePermission].map { role =>
          roleService.saveRole(role) map { _ =>
            Created
          } recover {
            case e: DatabaseException if e.getMessage().contains("E11000 duplicate key") =>
              BadRequest("role  with same name already exists")
            case NonFatal(e) =>
              InternalServerError(e.getMessage)
          }
        }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("invalid json")))
      }

//Model Class
    import java.util.UUID
    import play.api.libs.json.Json

    case class RolePermission(
     // roleName: Option[String],
      admin :List[String]
    )
    object RolePermission 
    {
     implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[RolePermission]    
    }

//Json

    {"admin":["mdyacc","viwacc"]}
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/1339516