# 415 Unsupported Media Type with Spring after all jackson jar added

Tags: angularjs, spring

This is my anular js to pass json to spring controller

```
$scope.submit = function() {

  $scope.json = JSON.parse(localStorage
    .getItem("itemDes"));

  var jsonlen = Object.keys($scope.json).length;
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonlen; i++) {
    var qnty = document
      .getElementById("qunty_" + i).value;
    // alert(qnty);
    var price = document.getElementById("subtot_" + i).value;

    $scope.object2 = {
      totquanty: qnty,
      totprice: price
    };
    angular.extend($scope.json[i], $scope.object2);

  }
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
    }
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify($scope.json));
  //localStorage.clear();
  var response = $http.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveCartOrder',
    "hiii");


  response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(data);
  });
  response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
      data: data
    }));
  });

};
```

This is my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCartOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {
  "Accept=*/*", "Content-Type=application/json"
})
public void saveCartOrder(@RequestBody CartBean cart) {
  System.out.println(cart.getItemname());

}
```

I have added the jackson jar to the project:
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

Still iam getting this 415 Unsupported Media Type  error.

Comment: have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11549679/6503002. He set the accept header in the request

Answer (score 0):

Remove headers and add `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` as you are setting it to `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveCartOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE )
public void saveCartOrder(@RequestBody CartBean cart) {
  System.out.println(cart.getItemname());

}
```

Doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8

Secondly, ensure @requestBody Cartbean is satisfied by looking at the json sent as part of the request . if it doesn`t mataches, it will not work as expected

Comment: I have added your code and import  org.springframework.http.MediaType;.But getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from MediaType to String[] error

Comment: This is my json data:[{"id":65,"itemname":"itemtemp","price":100,"discount":0,"qunty":12,"totquanty":"1","totprice":"100"}] And My CartBean :private int id;
 private String itemname;
 private float price;
 private float discount;
 private Integer qunty;
 private String totquanty;
 private String totprice;

Comment: @sumanbiswas use consume=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE instead. It return a String and it's the correct value.

Comment: @amicoderozer  still same error.i m not getting where i m doing the wrong.