# POST method not working when called from JQuery using $.post

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, post

I'm not really sure why my post method does not work. I think I've set it up correctly too. I have a Rest Controller that accepts the POST method. Below are the codes I used. Any help is appreciated.

For the JS part:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/WebApplicationService/service/registerUser", registrationDetails, function(data) {

    });
```

For the Server Part:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(@RequestBody final RegistrationBean pBean)
            throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("hello");

        try {
//          this.logic.register(pBean);
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

A few more information:
I've checked registrationDetails object and RegistrationBean and they both have the same fields and the same types. I've also annotated RegistrationBean with @Component. The controller that contains registerUser is mapped to "/service".

The error I get is `POST http://localhost:8080/WebApplicationService/service/registerUser 415 ()`

What else could I be missing?

Comment: `415` error basically means unsupported media type.. **[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)** might help you..

Comment: Thank you for that. I found out what I was missing. Apparently, I was missing dependencies in my pom.xml and I think Jackson is needed to convert JSON strings to POJO Objects. Basically, I added Jackson core and Jackson databind in my pom.xml and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was missing. Apparently, I was missing dependencies in my pom.xml and I think Jackson is needed to convert JSON strings to POJO Objects. Basically, I added Jackson core and Jackson databind in my pom.xml and it resolved the issue.
Following dependency is added to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, Jackson is needed for converting JSON to objects and vice versa.