# POST object using fetch() api

Tags: ajax, post, fetch

I'm trying to post some data using the fetch() api and I keep receiving a "400 - Bad Request" error.
I don't have any problem using the jQuery's $.ajax() method and I'm wondering what am I doing wrong:

**data**

```
let obj = {
    id_user: 57,
    id_category: 60,
    note: 'test'
}
```

**Using jQuery (working)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/devices',
    type: 'post',
    data: obj
}).fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
  })
```

**Using fetch() (not working)**

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/devices', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(obj)
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

**Response**

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3001/api/devices", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false…}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the fetch API:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class obj
    {
        public int id_user { get; set; }
        public int id_category { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }

    public class devicesController : ApiController
    {
        public string Post([FromBody]obj value)
        {
            //use newtonsoft json
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
     @{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#callAjax").click(function () {
                let obj = {
                    id_user: 57,
                    id_category: 60,
                    note: 'test'
                }

                //this worked for me, FYI, I USE different port than you
                //$.ajax({
                //    url: 'http://localhost:53110/api/devices',
                //    type: 'post',
                //    data: obj
                //}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //    alert(data);
                //}).fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                //    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                //    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                //    console.log("Status: " + status);
                //    console.dir(xhr);
                //})

                //https://davidwalsh.name/fetch - does not work in ie11
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc
                fetch('http://localhost:53110/api/devices', {
                    //I HAD TO add this headers because 415 unsupported media type
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify(obj)
                }).then(function (response) {
                    //alert(response)
                    //ADDED THIS https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch
                    response.json().then(function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    alert(error)
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="callAjax" id="callAjax" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```