# Not able to send JSON request to spring controller from Ajax

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to create my project template.

I'm trying to send a JSON request to my spring controller using Ajax, I tried by adding the content type of json etc. Its a POST request. however the trials got failed.

### index.jsp

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      

        $.ajax({ 
            url:"getNames",
            type:"POST", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({"name":"testName"}), 
            async: false,    
            cache: false,      
            dataType : "json",
             processData:false, 
             success: function(resposeJsonObject){
                // Success Action
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

### Controller

My total controller other than imports

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

// Produces JSON data
@RequestMapping(value="hello",produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String helloWorld() throws JSONException {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("my key", "my Value");
    return obj.toString();
}

// Accept JSON data
@RequestMapping(value="getNames", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Test addNewWorker(@RequestBody Test jsonString) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setName(jsonString.getName());
    System.out.println(test.getName());
    return test;
}
```

### Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### My Test class

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

My configuration file of spring

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="test" class="com.qiib.spring3.model.Test"></bean>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

### Error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

### Following JAR's are available in my project

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans- ""
spring-context-""
spring-core-""
spring-expression-""
spring-web-""
spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Yhen you tried to add the content type, did you try something like this : 
`@RequestMapping(value="getNames", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")` ?

Comment: hi Syed did you check the network tab?

Comment: @Thoomas, yes I tried with that and also , consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Comment: @Pradeep yes, this is the message which I see in network " The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

Comment: Try to remove content type or ContentType: false and in controller add produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Comment: @Syed Try to add `dataType : "json",` in your ajax call.

Comment: Try to send without stringify. Just  `data: {"name":"testName"},`

Comment: @Pradeep, I have already tried this and updated in comment too :(

Comment: @StanislavL, same error.. 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: @Thoomas, same error. I dont understand why its not able to support application/json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc pls have a look at this I think its because of your response body

Comment: @No pradeep.. tried with all these

Answer (score 0):

I've imported your code into mine project and it works absolutely fine. You should check your beans and pom.xml. I'm posting my code and result:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getNames", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody Test addNewWorker(@RequestBody Test jsonString) {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setName(jsonString.getName());
            System.out.println(test.getName());
            return test;
        }
```

index.js:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url:"getNames",
        type:"POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({"name":"testName"}), 
        async: false,    
        cache: false,      
        dataType : "json",
         processData:false, 
         success: function(resposeJsonObject){
            // Success Action
        }
    });
```

output:

```
2017-08-17 08:59:22.045  INFO 7092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-08-17 08:59:22.046  INFO 7092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-08-17 08:59:22.049  INFO 7092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 3 ms
testName
```

Comment: Also, can you post your pom.xml (if you are using maven) and annotations on controller

Comment: even I have posted the bean. Should I configure the bean in spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: Im not using maven, its a dynamic web project

Comment: Have you tried changing annotation from Controller  to @RestController ?

Comment: Can you plz tell me what all jar's have u included

Comment: I'm using maven, and I'm really not familiar with DWP, but i can try to help you. If i can see, you are making some hello world project and you are trying to expand it. Basicly, what you can do, put your project on github and i can fork it on my STS and see where the problem is.

Comment: Vinko, I'm sorry I cant use git here. But, I can post the total files and configuration files in this post itself. Is it ok?

Comment: Yeah sure, post it if you don't mind. As more information you gave to me, more I can help you. If i can't help you, other people may help you.

Comment: I have posted total details. Please let me know if you require any other info

Comment: I've got an idea. If you explicitly don't need to use dynamic web project you can transform project into maven project and then you can edit pom.xml and inject missing dependencies

Comment: But what makes the difference? Thats not the problem

Comment: Well, it makes difference for me, since I'm not familiar with DWP. I will try to dig this one out, and will answer you in half hour if i can do anything

Comment: Sure. DWB is a simple one. Just needed to copy jar's instead of adding dependencies. Just the flow of JAR is different.