# JIRA REST API for authentication in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to authenticate my user by following code.

```
    $.postJSON = function(url, data, callback, errorCallback) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': url,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'data': data,
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': callback,
            'error': errorCallback
        });
    };

    logindata = "{ 'username': admin, 'password': '********'}";

    $.postJSON ('https://****.****.net/rest/auth/1/session', logindata, function (data, textStatus) {
        alert (textStatus);
    }, function (objStatus) {
        alert (JSON.stringify(objStatus));
    });
```

but, got 2 error

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()
2. Failed to load https://jira URL/rest/auth/1/session: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://**.**.**.**:****' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.

any one can help me? why its happening ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, add

```
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
'data': JSON.stringify(data),
```

to `jQuery.ajax`. Check [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) for more details

For your second error, this is a CORS issue. Use a plugin for your browser. Download this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog and enable cors.