# Cannot POST Data in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, post, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a POST request using .NET CORE MVC by submitting a form. The call is successfully made from the view and looks like this:

[image]

My controller code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("fred-responses-report-result/{formId:int?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FredResponsesReportResult(int? formId, ReportFilters filters)
```

The *formId* param is passed through fine and set to 63, but the report filters object (below) is just `null`. The class is below, if it matters:

```
public class ReportFilters
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have read [this article](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc). I have tried removing the attributes from the model - didn't help. I tried pre-pending `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]` to the controller param, and it resulted in a 415 http error.

I am at a bit of a loss at how to get this to work at this point. If I look at the "view source" (in the screenshot) it seems like these are just being passed as HTML-encoded strings, rather than JSON, though I don't understand why. Regardless, what is the proper approach here?

**EDIT**, here is the code making the call:

```
            <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="row gray-background">
                <!--Date Filter-->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2 offset-1 bold-font">
                            <p>Submitted Date</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">

                            <div class="date datepicker fromDate">
                                <label for="fromDate">From</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="date datepicker toDate">
                                <label for="toDate">To</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="toDate" name="toDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.ReportFilters.ToDate">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Update Filters Button-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <button class="btn button-margin btn-primary"
                                    type="submit">
                                Update Filter
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: How did you post the data? Could you show your Ajax code?

Comment: Please share your view and the code used to post back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost("fred-responses-report-result/{formId:int?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FredResponsesReportResult(int? formId,[Bind("ToDate","FromDate")]ReportFilters filters)
 {
```

this should work.  Since you are using straight models (i believe) this instance, bind will allow you to target only the fields you wanted to be returned from the form..

without seeing the rest of the code associated with the form on the actual view and if you aren't doing AJAX posts (content-type not set for application/json) then `[FromBody]` will never work.

The next question is the route used actually expecting a variable named `formId` or is it using the default `id`?

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. The id comes from the url. As far as making the call, I will update - I basically have a form. I will come back to accept your answer. I might put a bounty on this. This feels "wrong", but it works great - really appreciate it.

Comment: Also don't forgot naming the form with Id=ReportFilters would help and making sure that each input is exact with naming using TagHelpers would help you out as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit form data in this format:

```
filters.fromDate: ..
filters.toDate: ...
```

instead of

```
fromDate: ...
toDate: ...
```