# HTTP 415 Errors when using JQuery to upload JSON to a Dropwizard based API

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, dropwizard

I have written a REST/JSON API using Dropwizard. Besides the internal unit tests, I've been testing it using the Restlet Chrome extension and curl. 
I've been using the Content-Type: "application/json" header in the HTTP requests. 
That works as intended.

Now I've been working on a JavaScript based frontend that accesses the API. Not being really deep into JavaScript, I went with JQuery. It works fine for GET requests. I've been struggling the last day to get POST requests working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help from you is highly appreciated!

About the API: The Dropwizard Resource Class looks as follows:

```
@Path("/documents")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DocumentsResource { 
    //generic stuff happening in the class, including internal data handling and the add() method

    @POST
    public Response addDocument(@NotNull @Valid TCDocuments documents){
      if(documents.getDocuments().length==0){
        Response response = Response.status(400).build();
        return response;
      }
    else if(documents.getDocuments().length>0){
        for(int i=0; i<documents.getDocuments().length; i++){
            TCDocument doc=documents.getDocuments()[i];
            add(doc);
        }
     }

    Response response = Response.ok().build();
    return response;
 }
}
```

The POJO TCDocuments contains an array of TCDocument POJOs. The finished JSON (as used as fixture in unit testing) is:

```
{
"documents":[
    {
        "id":-1,
        "label":"My label",
        "content":"My content",
        "url":""
    }]
}
```

I have tried multiple things to POST to it using JQuery. In my HTML page, there is a form named "createF", which I use to input data when posting to that interface. As mentioned I'm not really fit in JavaScript but following advice found here on StackOverflow I did the following to create a documents object within JavaScript and then tried to send it:

```
var form = $("#createF").serializeArray();
var documents = {
    documents: [
        {
            id: form[0].value,
            label: form[1].value,
            content: form[2].value,
            url: form[3].value
        }
    ]
};
var json = JSON.stringify(documents);
```

Using the console.log() command I figured out, that stringify puts the id in quotation marks. That is not accepted by my API, so I figured that that is the source of the occuring 415 errors. To work around, I bodged something together using string operators:

```
var json = "{ \"documents\":[{\"id\":-1,\"label\":\"metadata json\",\"content\":\"I am ignored\",\"url\":\"\"}]}";
```

Unfortunately this also results in 415 errors when I try to send it using:
    $.post(
        "../documents", 
        json, 
        function(response){
            console.log(resonse);
        }, 
        "json"
        );

As I found here, I should not only set the Content-Type as HTTP Header but also Accepted="application/json". [POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) I do not need to specify that header in the restlet client or curl. But maybe JQuery acts differently. What do I know? So I wrote the following code:

```
var url="../documents";
$.postJSON = function(url, json){
    return jQuery.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': url,
        'data': json,
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function(){
        console.log("successfully posted something");
        }   
    });
};
```

The good news is, that that didn't result in a 415 message but I got no reply from the API at all. The network log showed, that no packages left the browser when invoking the function. 
All I found here and on other sides is essentially more information about how to use $.post or $postJSON in JQuery. I tried all example variations of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ resulting in more 415 messages.

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I should do instead? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your `Accept': 'application/json'` appears to be missing a single quote in front of `Accept`

Comment: Hello @Justin-Pearce, thank you for the comment. That is a copy-paste error when posting it to stackoverflow and fixing the indentations. In the original source there is the quotation mark. I updated my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Justin-Pearce for the comment. When using $.ajax() instead of $.post() or $.postJSON() the following code works:

```
$("#createF").submit(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Uploading data");
                var form = $("#createF").serializeArray();
                console.log(form);
                var json = "{ \"documents\":[{\"id\":"+form[0].value+
                    ",\"label\":\""+form[1].value+
                    "\",\"content\":\""+form[2].value+
                    "\",\"url\":\""+form[3].value+"\"}]}";
                console.log(json);

                var url="../documents";


                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: json,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('something worked');
                        console.log('succes: '+data);
                    }
                 });

            });
```

The only funny thing is, that the success function doesn't seem to be triggered even though the operation successfully operates. I changed the response code of the API from 200 to 201 (created). This also doesn't seem to trigger the success function. Otherwise, this does what it is supposed to do.