# Problem with sent image and JSON object / Angular

Tags: angular, http-post

I have a problem with Angular Post method. I want o sent image and my model to the server. 
This is my service:

```
  pushFileToStorage(file: File, ct:CategoryModel): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file', file);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'api/cateogry/saveCategory',  {formdata ,ct} ,{
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

This is my commponenet :

```
  this.uploadService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload, this.category).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
      }
    });
```

I have  the error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-25T13:44:22.093+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------125126563049882524399172;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/api/product/createCategory"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
formdata.append('file', JSON.stringify(file));

please visit:
[POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)