# Bad request AJAX post to Spring API

Tags: json, ajax, spring, jsp, post

I'm sending JSON data to my Spring API but I always get a bad request. I have tried some things. At first, `chanceReward` was of type `Map<String, Object>`. Later I thought it should be a `String` but it still had a bad request. I researched and thought I needed `consumes = "application/json"` in the annotation but result is the same. Not sure anymore what to do. Below is the code for my API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chance/{id}/saveChanceRewards", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> saveChanceRewards(@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestBody String chanceRewards) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(chanceRewards);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(JObject.getString("name") + " " + JObject.getString("weight"));
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        _log.error("Error parsing JSON");
    }

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    // TODO

    return map;
}
```

Below is the ajax code (inside a .jsp):

```
    let arrayRewards = [];
    // get the data from dynamic list of text fields
    for (let i = 1; i <= chanceRewardCount; i++) {
        arrayRewards.push({
            name: $('#chanceRewardName' + i).val(),
            weight: $('#chanceRewardWeight' + i).val()
        });
    }

    let data = {'data': arrayRewards};
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json',    
        url: "${home}/chance/${id}/saveChanceRewards",
        method: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('response', response);  
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        }
    });
```

I'm using Spring Framework 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

That mean the server not able to understand the request from your ajax.

First, change `@RequestBody String chanceRewards` to `@RequestBody ChanceRewards chanceRewards`

And define `ChanceRewards` and `ChanceReward` class.

```
class ChanceReward {

    private String name;

    private String weight;

    // Getter Setter ...

}

class ChanceRewards {

    private List<ChanceReward> data;

    // Getter Setter ...

}
```

If still failed, try open inspect mode and click network tab to check the request send from ajax.

Comment: But I'm sending a JSON stringified object? But okay I'll try this.

Comment: I got Unsupported media type. Do I need to annotate or do something with ChanceRewards?

Comment: @Zik, maybe you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc) to set the accept application type in headers?

Comment: @Zik, Or you maybe can try remove the 'consumes', like `@RequestMapping(value = "/chance/{id}/saveChanceRewards", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")` because my application still work without define it. Most important, you need to inspect and check whether the request header and content are send out correctly.

Comment: It's still the same. For the request header, it is correct.

Comment: Never found a solution to my problem so I just resorted back to using a <form:form> and I used this solution

Answer (score 0):

Replace double quotes in your `url: "${home}/chance/${id}/saveChanceRewards",` by backtick.

Comment: Tried it, it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things going on here, so let's work on them!

First, I see you've stringified the data into `jsonData`, but your actual ajax post has `data: data` instead.  Easy fix, just swap in the right variable.

Second thing I notice is that you're wrapping the rewards array in an *object* (with `data = {'data': arrayRewards}`) but your Java code expects the *array itself* (JSONArray) right out of the request body.  So this will also throw an exception.  You don't have to wrap the array with an object if it's not needed.

Lastly, you mention that you always get a "bad request", but what exactly do you mean?  An "HTTP 400" error?  Some other HTTP error?  It might be useful to give more info on the **exact** error(s) you see on the javascript side and on the Java server side.

All the other things like worrying about making a ChanceReward / ChanceRewards class, accepts/consumes/produces headers, etc., are superfluous at this point.  They are boilerplate niceties and you don't need any of them for this to work correctly.

Comment: Oh, I've already tried your first and second points, it's not working. Yes, I mean the HTTP 400 bad request. When I tried karfai's solution below now I get 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: So I copied your code, made the two suggestions I made above to make sure the JS and Spring Boot code have the same expectations, and everything worked fine.  Let me know if you still have issues.  The key point is for the JS code and the Spring Boot code to be consistent. As posted above there are the two inconsistencies noted.