# API to save an entity is not working, status 415

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm working on the backend of a Web App using Java. I need to create an API that allows to save a project related to an existing client of a given company. "project" and "client" are two entities, and there is a `OneToMany` relation between them (a client can have many projects, but each project is related to just one client). This is my code:

```java
@PostMapping("/{clientId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> addProject(@PathVariable Long clientId, @RequestBody Project project) {
  try {
    Optional<Client> client = clientRepository.findById(clientId);
    if (client.isPresent())
      project.setClient(client.get());
    project.setTasks(new ArrayList<>());
    project.setEmployees(new ArrayList<>());
    Project saved = projectRepository.save(project);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(saved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to execute it, i get the error **415 Unsupported Media Type**. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I found out that the problem was the `@RequestBody` annotation. So I substituted it with `@ModelAttribute`. In this way, I don't get the 415 error anymore. However, the object `project` isn't populated with the data that I pass in the request body: all the fields are set to `null`...

Comment: Did you pass `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your annotation at the class/method-level of your controller?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes, I've just added it, but it gives the same error...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611186/1762224

Comment: Maybe a header problem? Try setting Content and Accept headers to json when doing the request

Comment: @SantiagoWagner unfortunately, the headers are okay but still it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON payload you're sending? I'd like to try that example on my end to help you figure this error out