# Can not Send POST request to @RequestBody in Spring, error 415

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, spring-restcontroller

I am working currently on a project and I need to send a POST request to spring. I looked or several hours already for a solution and didn't find one to work. The request worked when I developed that part. The problem is that after creating some new functionalities(2 new endpoint in another controller) the POST requests for creating or updating the entities stopped working without changing code in the specific area.

The Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping
public class SensorController {  

@PostMapping(value = "/createSensor", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> insertSensor(@RequestBody SensorDto sensorDto){
        UUID sensorId = sensorService.createSesor(sensorDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(sensorId,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

The part with consumes and produces wasn't there originally, I tried it because saw on other posts but doesn't helped the situation.

The SensorDto:

```
public class SensorDto extends RepresentationModel<SensorDto> {
private UUID id;
private String description;
private Integer maxValue;
private Device device;
```

The call from POSTMAN:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lacxa.png)

The headers: [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNaE.png)

Can someone help me to get it to work again?

EDIT: The code asked from the other controller

```
@PostMapping("/addSensorToDevice")
public ResponseEntity<UUID> addSensor(@RequestBody DeviceSensorLinkDto deviceSensorLinkDto){
    System.out.println("OOO: " + deviceSensorLinkDto.toString());
    if(deviceService.addSensor(deviceSensorLinkDto)){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceSensorLinkDto.getDeviceId(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceSensorLinkDto.getDeviceId(), HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
}

@PostMapping("/addClientToDevice")
public ResponseEntity<UUID> addClient(@RequestBody DeviceClientLinkDto deviceClientLinkDto){
    System.out.println("OOO: " + deviceClientLinkDto.toString());
    if(deviceService.addClient(deviceClientLinkDto)){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceClientLinkDto.getDeviceId(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(deviceClientLinkDto.getDeviceId(), HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

And this one works and also the requests for deleting a Sensor entity.

Comment: You can try adding header `Accept: application/json`. But UUID is not a valid JSON, so you can also try replacing `produces=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to `TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE`

Comment: Could you share SensorDto constructor please?

Comment: @geobreze I added the header but nothing changed

Comment: @geobreze Tried changing the header Accept in postman, it says 406 not accepted, this when I put the TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, if I change it back to JSON_VALUE is still gives me 415

Comment: @mamunmohamed I use Lombok and have the NoArgs and AllArgs constructor for the SensorDto, but the other fields I will set later before saving the entity to the db

Comment: Why are you returning UUID as a ResponseEntity?

Comment: @RolandGonczel you should try a combination of `Accept: text/plain` and `produces= TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE`

Comment: Also you could try without implementing property ```consumes``` because spring by defaul has integrated JSON library for raccept and response request.

Comment: A similar question like -> this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc

Comment: Tried each suggestion, still 415

Comment: Can you please add also the code that you added in the other Controller? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias updated the question

Comment: It makes no sense that it simply stopped working after adding those two new endpoints. Something else must have changed. Additionally, what do you see in the logs?

Comment: The warnings was disabled as I observed, Got this warning, at least now I have a starting point:  2021-11-29 12:29:03.640  WARN 2948 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class ro.tuc.ds2020.dtos.SensorDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'

Comment: Are you using `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` in your application?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I used it on a OneToMany relation. The problem seemed to be that I used it in a OneToOne relation too. I deleted that and now it work. Not sure if the issue is that it was on a OneToOne or something else

Comment: No, that is not the issue. I will add an answer.

Comment: And now I know why I added that. Now in my get method it returns a infinite cycle, the sensor prints the device and the device prints back the sensor and so on..

Comment: Please check my answer below. Removing the annotations is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` in your application and as a consequence, you must provide a name for all pairs as follows:

```java
@JsonBackReference(value = "something")

@JsonManagedReference(value = "something")
```

```java
@JsonBackReference(value = "something-else")

@JsonManagedReference(value = "something-else")
```

You can find some information about this in the [reference documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html):

> Logical have for the reference property pair; used to link managed and
> back references. Default name can be used if there is just single
> reference pair (for example, node class that just has parent/child
> linkage, consisting of one managed reference and matching back
> reference).