# Formatting json to map Asp.Net Core Model binding

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I have an Asp.Net Core web application client which uses Ajax JQuery to post changes to server.
In a particular page, I have to append some data to the request so the model gets populated additionnal properties values because the data is created with an editable table, so there is no regular input fields for this data. However I cannot find a way to format the json for the model mapping. The server doesn't map values at all for this additionnal property.

Here is the model (simplified) :

```
public class ProductCategoryModel {
    public ProductCategoryDto Category { get; set; } = new();
}

public class ProductCategoryDto
{
    public string Description { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<ProductSubCategoryDto> ListProductSubCategories { get; set; } = new();
}

public class ProductSubCategoryDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Here is the original request data, which is working fine :

```
[{"name":"Model.Category.Description","value":"CATEGORY"}]
```

I tried to add an array like this :

```
[{"name":"Model.Category.Description","value":"CATEGORY"},
{"name":"Model.Category.ListProductSubCategories",
 "value":[
    {"Id":null,"Description":"Nouvelle sous-catégorie"},
    {"Id":null,"Description":"Nouvelle sous-catégorie 2"}
 ]
}]
```

And I tried to add each array item like this :

```
[{"name":"Model.Category.Description","value":"CATEGORY"},
{"name":"Model.Category.ListProductSubCategories","value":{"Id":null,"Description":"Nouvelle sous-catégorie"}},
{"name":"Model.Category.ListProductSubCategories","value":{"Id":null,"Description":"Nouvelle sous-catégorie 2"}}]
```

So I want to populate the ListProductSubCategories to get the values in the server-side's model, but I always receive an empty list. How can I achieve that?

Ajax call :

```
function mapAssociatedToSimpleArray(obj) {
    var a3 = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) { return obj[k]; })
    return a3;
}

var data = $("#form").serializeArray();

var listSubCategories = mapAssociatedToSimpleArray(_dataSource); // <--  _dataSource is an associated array data to be appended to the request
                
data.push({
    name: "Model.Category.ListProductSubCategories", value: listSubCategories
});
        
$.ajax({
    url: "/inv/ProductsCategoriesController/Edit/@Model.Categorie.Id",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    headers: {'RequestVerificationToken': $(".AntiForge input").val() },
    success: function (data) {        
        // ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        if (utils.hasJsonStructure(xhr.responseText)) {
            $("#form").handleModelErrors(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
        notifications.error();
    }            
});
```

Controller Post action :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid id, ProductCategoryModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return ModelState.ReturnErrorsToClient(Response);
    }

    model.Category.Id = id;
    await _productsCategoriesBackend.UpdateProductCategory(model.Category);

    return new JsonResult(model.Category.Id);            
}
```

In controller, the parameter model.Category.ListProductSubCategories is always empty.

EDIT

I should have made it clearer that the table data are inserted with input fields, but the fields are displayed only when a row needs to be edited. After editing is done, the input data is written to the table as well as in a json array, and the input fields are removed. So there is no fields available to the form when the form needs to be submitted. That's why I need to send a formatted asp.net structure of this table model when the form is submitted.

Comment: you should be able to bind a class object to the incoming json.   RIght now it looks like a list of a class with "name" and "value".   You should include the ajax call, the view, and the controller code.  Seems like whatever you are doing now can be simplified.  (Or you can just append to a FormData object, and send that as standard POST data, which this sort of looks like...)

Comment: Do you have custom model binding for your application? Besides, could you please share all the related codes like  controller or else to let us understand better for your requriement.

Comment: @pcalkins, I added the ajax call and controller receiving save action

Comment: @Brando Zhang,  I added the ajax call and controller receiving save action

Comment: you'll make your life much easier if you just use a formdata object and post that.  So: thisForm = document.getElementById(id);  
    var formData = new FormData(thisForm);... then use data: formData in your call... no need to add anti-forgery token as it will be in the form.  Then bind controller to the model you used in the form (.cshtml).

Comment: @pcalkins I added some details about the table data input. The table is inside the form tag but there is no input fields inside the table when the form is submitted.

Comment: we can't see enough code here to be more helpful, but you'll want to comform the data in your call to your controller's model.   (I'd make a "view model" that matches so that you are only binding to one class object, or a list of the class object)  You can append to a new formData object if that's helpful, but since you are already building a JSON array, just build that to match the controller's model.  You can send that and use FromBody to have your controller bind it.

Comment: Thank you for your help @pcalkins. It seems that I would need to post the whole MVC code. That's silly. Anyway, that's what I'm trying to do (matching the controller's model) but I can't make it work.

Comment: you're complicating things with serializing and mapping in your JS... handle it all when you build the JSON array.  It might help you to just copy/paste your controller's model into notepad and then convert it line by line into a new JS "type".  (initialize/build an empty JSON array with the correct structure/field names first...)  OR go the other way around... converting the JSON into a C# model/class object that you can then bind the JSON to.  Usually it's easier to go model->JSON because you already used that model to create the form.

Comment: simplest would be just to keep the form... if you used asp-for's or html helpers there then you don't need any JSON.  You can hide those fields by setting styles instead of wiping them out of the DOM before submitting.  Then send the formData object and it'll bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a recipe that is working well.

For the action method, I added an explicit [FromBody] attribute on the model parameter, so the framework uses the Json input formatter.

For the ajax call, I need to add the Content-Type header, as well as stringify the data.

```
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
headers: {
    "RequestVerificationToken": $(".antiForge input").val() , 
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
},
```

I am then able to pass a json object matching the model properties, instead of trying to create a form-encoded object with the data.

I used the jquery.serializeToJSON plugin to build a nice object of the form fields :

```
var data = $('#form').serializeToJSON();
data.Category.ListProductSubCategories = _dirtyRows;
```

Then I can add additional property to this object to complete the model with the table's dirty rows data. Being able to pass a json object is much more handier than fiddling with a "x-www-form-urlencoded" object.

The following articles helped me a lot in finding my way through this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

[POST JSON fails with 415 Unsupported media type, Spring 3 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc)

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Serialize-Form-Data-Into-JSON-Object-In-jQuery-serializeToJSON.html