# Send JSON using PUT method

Tags: html, json, http-headers, put, developer-console

I'm currently stuck on this challenge I'm trying to complete. On the webpage there is a text field, containing some text like so: {name:example, state: example. etc:example}

And it wants me to use the PUT method to send the JSON. And I am genuinely lost and confused. I've tried many many different ideas, that I have found around the web, but nothing has worked as of yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311579/put-ajax-request Should lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If your field contains 
`{name:example, state: example. etc:example}`
Which is not a proper JSON or Javascript object at first. And If you are having a regular JSON or js object as an input of a text field then you can use Ajax to send put request to your server like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/server_url',
    data: JSON.stringify(your_data)
    success: function(result) {
       // result from server
    }
});
```

you should also consider using JSON.stringify(your_data) before ajax Req which will convert your data to proper JSON.